# All my Dialogflow agents recently stopped responding to messenger Welcome Event without changes being made to the agents at all

Tags: dialogflow-es

Hope you're well.

I've set up a few basic chatbots for Facebook Messenger in December 2018 - using Dialogflow. However, recently they've all stopped responding to the initial "Get Started" button that you press on messenger in order to start communicating with the bot. They all worked fine before, and I haven't made any changes, so I am not sure why all of them have stopped responding all of a sudden. Below is what my Default Welcome intents look like:

- Input Contexts: None
- Output Contexts: A few based on what Quick Reply the human selects
- Events: Dialogflow Welcome, Facebook Messenger Welcome
- Training Phrases: "Get Started"
- Action and Parameters: No parameters. There is a text-box which has "input.welcome" written in it. However, I am not sure what that means, and I didn't notice it previously.
- Responses: a FB Messenger quick reply response. The intent is NOT set as the end of conversation.
- Fulfillment: Webhook call for this intent and slot filling are both OFF.

I've tried removing all training phrases, removing the Dialogflow event and just having the FB event. I've also tried removing the "input.welcome" action, but I'm having no success.

All I need is my Chatbot to reply with the default welcome intent when a user presses "Get Started", but I am not able to make it work anymore, even when creating new agents. All help is appreciated.

Many thanks,

-Simeon

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have checked to see if you are subscribed to "messaging_postbacks". If not follow the steps below.

Step 1: Go to developers.facebook.com page.
Step 2: Select your app (in this case the chatbot with the issue).
Step 3: Scroll down to the "webhooks" (see the image in the link below).
Step 4: Click on "Edit" and select "messaging_postbacks". (also in second linked image).
Step 5: Save and Test chatbot again.

I hope this helps as the "Get Started" of facebook messager is a postback message. Let me know your results.

[webhook setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2aFn.jpg)

[enabling "messaging_postbacks" image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgwg8.jpg)